# Passwordless keybased authentication in linux not working

Tags: linux, ssh, password-less

I have server A and Server B.

Iam able to ssh from server A to server B as 'root' user password less successfully. I have another non-root normal user in server B, My requirement is to ssh from server A to Server B using that non-root normal user.

Here is what I did;
1) Copied the public key from Server A to Server B's non-root normal user authorized_keys files kept in .ssh directory of non-root normal user.
2)On Server B, given the permissions 700 to .ssh directory and given 600 permissions to authorized_keys file.

It is still asking for password, it is not working as expected(passwordless).

Please help.

FYI, root user login from Server A to Server B is working perfectly passwordless and I followed the above steps only. Surprised to see it is not working for a normal user.

Comment: If you can do `ssh root@serverB` and it works without asking for a password, then on `serverB` simply copy `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys` to `~user/.ssh/authorized_keys` and make it readable by `user`.

Comment: Alex, thanks for the response. I tried what you mentioned here, but still no luck.

Comment: I ran the ssh command in verbose mode and go the following
]# ssh -v user@ipaddress
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
 Applying options for *
Connecting to <ipaddress> [<ipaddress>] port 22.
Connection established.
permanently_set_uid: 0/0

Comment: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent

Comment: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
Host '<ipaddress>' is known and matches the RSA host key.
Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:221
ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received

Comment: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Next authentication method: publickey
Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa
Next authentication method: password
user@<ipaddress>'s password:

Answer (score 0):

Iam able to fix this issue using the below command;

restorecon -R -v /home/

Iam now able to do keybased authentication for non-root user successfully

Answer (score 0):

On server B for other user, .ssh directory permission would be 755 and 644 for authorized_keys . This should work

Answer (score 0):

Use below commands as root user-

1. ssh-keygen [Leave everything default and enter]
2. ssh-copy-id server_ip

Then it will ask for remote server password and then you can login to remote server using-

1. ssh server_ip